# Hovering over top-bar picture should show user card

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, user-card

Currently, when hovering over the tiny user-picture in the top-bar, only the user name in shown.

Feature request: Show one's own user-card instead - in <s>the same</s> almost the same way it is displayed on all other occurrences of the user-picture. That is, the user-card should appear a little below the mouse, such that hovering over rep or badges is still possible.

In this manner it would be possible to easily select links given in the profile.

Comment: This seems like a pretty minor use case!

Comment: Not many users have links in their profiles. Especially like the number of links in your profile!

Comment: I'd think that most people hovering over their own gravatar are about to click on it to go to their Profile/Activity pages. I don't need to see my (non-existent) bio or location and I can't imagine most other people would find that useful.

Answer (score 2):

The card is large enough that it would get in the way of the other UI elements and become bothersome. What might be nice is make the name in the tooltip a link to the card, that would take up no additional space.

Comment: If the user-card appears in *exactly* the same way, as by hovering over a user-picture, it would block hoverimg over the rep-points. So the user-card should appear a bit below.

Comment: It might be big enough that it would then block the 'Questions' button or more depending on resolution.

Comment: But that (blocking quesitons) cannot be a problem: simply move the mouse away (it's much less obvious for the other hoverable items in the top-bar)